# Accelerometer vs. Intel RealSense in VS 2015

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2015, accelerometer, realsense

I am trying to start developing a Windows Phone/Tablet App on Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) that makes use of both an accelerometer and a depth image from a RealSense camera. However, I'm stuck at the very beginning, when choosing the project template. A Windows Forms project already has all the sensors libraries, but when I try to import the specific RealSense library libpxccpp2c.dll, I get a message:

"A reference to '---' could not be found. Please make sure that the file is accesible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component".

When, on the other hand, I'm creating a WPF project as it is suggested in RealSense tutorials, then the Windows.Devices.Sensors library containing the accelerometer class becomes unavailable, the library may not be seen in the "add reference" menu. The only [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSBG0vNlRVg) I was able to find solves this by including projects from WindowsAPI code Pack, which is by now also unavailable.

A noob-level explanation needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Unity?  Have you read https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?doc_devguide_unity__application.html
On the WPF - have you looked at https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/12/05/project-template-to-develop-wpf-applications-with-intel-realsense

Comment: Thanks, I've asked this question on the RealSense Forums and got an exhaustive answer with a code sample. The problem was to add the Windows.Devices library, which was solved by specifying the target platform (Windows 8.1 or 10) in the project file.